# Other two fields are required if the third field is not empty

Tags: javascript, html

I have three textfields namely :

- State Code
- Country Code
- Telephone number

The value of StateCode and Country code is set by default.
If the Telephone Number textfield is entered, I want the other  two fields to be made mandatory.
If the Telephone Number is empty then it is not required. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create this fiddle:

**html**

```
<label id="lblStateCode">State Code</label>
<input type="text" id="stateCode" value="585" />
<label id="lblCountryCode">Country Code</label>
<input type="text" id="countryCode" value="552" />
<label id="lblPhone">Phone</label>
<input type="text" id="phone" />
```

**js**

```
$("#phone, #stateCode, #countryCode").on("blur",function(){
if($("#phone").val() != ""){

    if($("#stateCode").val() == ""){
        $("#lblStateCode").addClass("errorClass");
    }
    else{
        $("#lblStateCode").removeClass("errorClass");
    }

    if($("#countryCode").val() == ""){
        $("#lblCountryCode").addClass("errorClass");
    }
    else{
        $("#lblCountryCode").removeClass("errorClass");
    }

}
    else{
       $("#lblStateCode").removeClass("errorClass");
        $("#lblCountryCode").removeClass("errorClass");
    }   
});
$(function(){
if($("#phone").val() != ""){

    if($("#stateCode").val() == ""){
        $("#lblStateCode").addClass("errorClass");
    }
    else{
        $("#lblStateCode").removeClass("errorClass");
    }

    if($("#countryCode").val() == ""){
        $("#lblCountryCode").addClass("errorClass");
    }
    else{
        $("#lblCountryCode").removeClass("errorClass");
    }

}
    else{
       $("#lblStateCode").removeClass("errorClass");
       $("#lblCountryCode").removeClass("errorClass");
    } 
});
```

**css**

```
.errorClass{
    color:red;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8f4ZP/20/)

Comment: Let me know if you want submit button to chech the conditions.

Comment: Your answer works but I need to display the message below the textfield. Is it possible, instead of highlighting the textfield

Comment: I want message to be displayed as state code required, country code required when phone is non empty

Answer (score 0):

u need to apply jquery validations:

```
$("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    State: { required: function () {
                            if ($('#Telephone').val() != '') return true;
                            else return false;
                        },
                    Country: { required: function () {
                            if ($('#Telephone').val() != '') return true;
                            else return false;
                        }
                  }
               messages: {
                    State: { required: "error messge" },
                    Country: { required: "error messge" }
                }
         });
```